# Unable to resolve a dependency in react native maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

I have create react native application. There I am using react-native-maps. When bundle is building it laves this error on the console.

> Unable to resolve "./lib/components/MapHeatmap.js" from
>   "node_modules\react-native-maps\index.js"

I look for a solution but I was unable to do so. And I have not any clue for what should do for this error.Thank you

Comment: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/react-native-community/react-native-maps/3099/537074656

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error just now, try `sudo npm uninstall react-native-maps` and install it again with expo comand (if you are using expo).

Comment: Which expo command should one use to install it again?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue in react native (expo)
For me clearing the cache worked...
just type this command

```
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 0):

in  cli project run this command on your project
npm  cache clean --force
then reinstall the node module ......
then npm install